# How to make a second capture group optional without messing up the rest of the regex?

Tags: regex

I try to match the first and last digit of a string in either their numeral form or their written out form. It is possible there isn't a second digit, so the second capture group should be optional. If you know you know.

What I came up with: ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/cb9Mzy/1))

```
^.*?(?<first>\d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero).*(?<last>\d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero)?.*?$`
```

Example cases:

```
two1nine
eightwothree
abcone2threexyz
xtwone3four
4nineeightseven2
zoneight234
7pqrstsixteen
8zckvmtmbjtdqprvfxtkmgmmtgck
```

However this doesn't work as expected. Can someone please please point out where I went wrong. I'm aware I could solve it without regex, but now I'm inclined to improve my regex skills and learn how to solve a problem like this.

Comment: LIke this? `^.*?(?<first>\d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero)(?:.*(?<last>\d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero))?.*$` https://regex101.com/r/pGbipE/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I guess so haha, thank you. I understand there is a non-capturing group now around the capturing group. I just don't understand yet why it's needed.

Comment: I have added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the named capture group optional like this:

```
(?<last>\d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero)?
```

You can make the whole part including the `.*` and the named capture group optional like this to get the optional *last occurrence*:

```
(?:.*(?<last>\d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero))?
```

Note that the `.*?` at the end does not have to be non greedy.

```
^.*?(?<first>\d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero)(?:.*(?<last>\d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero))?.*$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGbipE/1).

---

Because the first part in your pattern `.*?` is **non greedy**, it will try to match as least as possible characters for the named group "first".
Then it matches the end of the string with `.*`, and at the end of the string, the group "last" is optional so there is no need to backtrack.

But if you use a group that you make optional as a whole that matches a non optional value inside, it will try to match `.*` and then one of the group "last". The preceding `.*` here can backtrack to match one of the alternatives.

If there is no match match, it can then suffice as the whole group is optional.